# How to easily compare local and remote files via SFTP

Tags: windows-7, ftp, comparison, dreamweaver, sftp

I would like to compare local and remote files via sftp or other method, dreamweaver has the option of doing this in your favorite merge editor (i like winmerge), but I am not using dw at this juncture. Are there any other decent (windows7) programs out there that do synchronize and compare nicely?

Comment: ultracompare does it, but it is convoluted method, manually save remote to temp folder then compare

Comment: I appreciate the link to Beyond Compare... but, is there a program out there that more closely follows the way that dw does it? With dw you can see which files in a directory are newer than the remote and just right click to compare local and remote?

Comment: you should update the question by editing it and not post the corrections to comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beyond Compare does (using our SFTP components BTW), but the way is not quite obvious -- you need to enter the URL in the form of "sftp://username@host.tld/path/to/directory/" as a directory to compare. I have yet to find how to store this string in some reusable way in Beyond Compare.

Upd: Forgot to mention that Beyond Compare handles regular FTP and FTP-over-TLS as well.

Comment: Doesn't BeyondCompare's session save the string?

Comment: @nevets1219 should save, as part of the session (which is probably ok for most scenarios). There's an FTP/SFTP account manager as well, but again the way to use it was not obvious from the first glance.

Comment: Just tested and in BeyondCompare it stores the URL in the saved sessions.

Comment: SFTP or FTP over SSL is supported in version 3, but not in version 2. You can use a separate tunneling software and point Beyond Compare 2.x to localhost and the custom port that tunnels you to the SFTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

We use Beyond Compare here too. In DreamWeaver you can identify a compare program to use during synchronization - click CTRL-U to open the Preferences dialog box; the option you want is about half way down: "File Compare". There you enter the *.exe program location for the compare application you wish to interact with DreamWeaver. If you DreamWeaver is connected to a remote server click on the root folder or a folder you wish to compare, right click and choose 'Synchronize'. Dreamweaver will use it's FTP settings to find differences in files, if you choose compare the FTP (or SFTP) facilities in DreamWeaver will download the remote file to a temporary location and will engage the Compare Software you have instructed it to in your DreamWeaver Preferences.

Comment: yes I love that feature in dreamweaver but dont use dw anymore, my question does any ftp program have the same options of synchronization and comparison....